# Down casting multiple protocol Array<protocol<P1, P2>> to Array<P1>

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols, swift2

So I have two arrays

```
var arrayOne:Array<protocol<P1,P2>>
var arrayTwo:Array<P1>
```

Where P1 and P2 are protocols.

Question is how to make downcasting operation

```
arrayTwo = arrayOne as Array<P1>
```

What i get from Xcode is:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Array<protocol<P1, P2>>' to specified type 'Array<P1>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the elements of the array, not the array itself.

```
arrayTwo = arrayOne.map { $0 as P1 }
```

Or as MartinR stated, there is even no need to cast the element.

```
arrayTwo = arrayOne.map { $0 }
```

Comment: Interestingly, even assignment through the "identity map" with `arrayTwo = arrayOne.map { $0 }` makes the code compile. This is strange because upcasting the entire array *does* work for sub/superclasses, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169839/merge-swift-array-with-same-superclass.

Comment: @MartinR the type of Element is known from arrayTwo declaration, so i think this is 'normal'

Comment: @user3441734 It might be "normal", but is it definitely not intuitive. Which is what Swift is supposed to be. There is also no conceivable reason for this to require a `map`.

Comment: @MartinR hm... may be this is cleaner to see 'typealias U = P1
var arrayTwo: Array<U> = arrayOne.map{ (e) -> U in e }' it so no casting, but conversion

Comment: @user3441734 how is that cleaner? As MartinR stated, casting is not even needed.

Comment: @RMenke i see, that arratOne and arrayTwo are different types. the element which conform to composition protocol<P1,P2> is down-casted to protocol P1 in transforming function map. that is my point of view. the type of P1 is known from declaration of arrayTwo. where i make the mistake in my imagination?

Comment: @RMenke "protocol P1{}
struct A: P1{}

let arr: Array<A> = []
let arr1: Array<P1> = arr.map{ $0 }" or even simpler 'let a = A()
let p: P1 = a'

Comment: @user3441734 This is probably a mute discussion, since it is about something Apple will most likely fix. But `arrayTwo = arrayOne.map { $0 }` is a whole lot cleaner and easier to read than `var arrayThree = arrayOne.map{ (e) -> P1 in e }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98012/discussion-between-user3441734-and-r-menke).

Comment: @user3441734 yes but you try to do that with array of struct implement protocol. try with 2 protocols, there is problem. And when you do map in this case array that you get is the same but casted. I check addresses of data inside casted array

Comment: @KamilWasąg as you can see from the answers and from the discussion here, if works with composite protocol too. the type of array is different, there is no change to cast from one type to other. you have to convert your array and down-cast the elements (or let the compiler to do the job for you) inside the map block.

Comment: @KamilWasąg 'protocol P1{}
protocol P2{}
var arrayOne:Array<protocol<P1,P2>> = []
var arrayTwo:Array<P1> = arrayOne.map { $0 } // it works,

// because it is just sweet equivalent of

var arrayTwo2 = arrayOne.map { (c) -> P1 in
    return c as P1
}'

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol P1{}
struct A: P1{}
// everybody knows, that
let a = A()
// (1)
let p: P1 = a
// or (2)
let p1 = a as P1

let arr: Array<A> = []
// has type
print(arr.dynamicType) // Array<A>
// (3) the array is converted to different type here !!
let arr1: Array<P1> = arr.map{ $0 }
print(arr1.dynamicType) // Array<P1>

// arr and arr1 are differnet types!!!
// the elements of arr2 can be down casted as in (1) or (2)
// (3) is just an equivalent of
typealias U = P1
let arr3: Array<U> = arr.map { (element) -> U in
    element as U
}
print(arr3.dynamicType) // Array<P1>


// the array must be converted, all the elements are down casted in arr3 from A to P1
// the compiler knows the type so ii do the job like in lines (1) or (2)
```