# Assign value to a two-dimensional array in swift

Tags: swift

I have a snippet of code like below:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
}

struct SomeObject: SomeProtocol {
}

struct Test {

    var arr: [[SomeProtocol]]

    mutating func testFunction(objs:[[SomeObject]]) {
        self.arr = objs
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SomeObject` confirm the protocol, but the compiler shows me an

```
error " cannot assign value of type '[[SomeObject]]' to type '[[SomeProtocol]]'".
```

Can somebody tell me the reason?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This could be a similar issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257678/down-casting-multiple-protocol-arrayprotocolp1-p2-to-arrayp1.

Comment: What if you try to cast the array? Anyway it has to do via covariance and controvariance. `SomeObject` is `SomeProtocol` but `[[SomeObject]]` is not `[[SomeProtocol]]`. Probably you need to cast each element. This was the same in .net 3.5, and it has been "resolved" in .net 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `[[SomeObject]]` is not the same type as `[[SomeProtocol]]` - see @TeeJay's comment above. The *how* is solved like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
}

struct SomeObject: SomeProtocol {
}

struct Test {

    var arr: [[SomeProtocol]]

    mutating func testFunction(objs:[[SomeObject]]) {
        self.arr = []
        for a in objs {
            var innerArray = [SomeProtocol]()
            for e in a {
                innerArray.append(e)
            }
            self.arr.append(innerArray)
        }
    }
}
```

Or, as @MartinR pointed out, you could use `map`.

If I try to short-circuit the inner loop with

```
    self.arr = []
    for a in objs {
        self.arr.append(a)
    }
```

I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Array<SomeObject>' to expected argument type [SomeProtocol]", which, on one level, is entirely correct - they are not the same - it's the elements, not the collection, which conform to the protocol. Array assignment doesn't dig down to the final element types for protocol conformance, unless you do it explicitly.

This is not entirely surprising - you wouldn't expect the following to work:

```
struct SomeOther1 {
    var a : SomeProtocol
}

struct SomeOther2 {
    var a : SomeObject
}

let x = SomeOther2(a: SomeObject())
let y: SomeOther1 = x // ERROR
```

whilst this should (and does) work:

```
let x = SomeOther2(a: SomeObject())
let y = SomeOther1(a: x.a)
```

Since Arrays are `Struct`s that use generics, we can try the same using generics:

```
struct SomeOther<T> {
    var a: T
}

let z = SomeOther<SomeObject>(a: SomeObject()) // OK, of course
let w = SomeOther<SomeProtocol>(a: SomeObject()) // OK, as expected
let v: SomeOther<SomeProtocol> = z // Doesn't work - types are not the same.
```

Comment: Yep, it's true I can solve the problem like this, but I want to know `why`. Anyway, thank you

Comment: Reasonably certain of the *why* now - updated answer.